# Scrapy: return value if element belongs to a specific class

Tags: python, if-statement, xpath, scrapy

I'm currently working on a Web Scraping project to scrape Data from a Newsletter Forum. For this I need to show if the comment was written by a staff member or by a reader/ customer. If the comment was written by a staff member, I want to write "Admin", if not "Customer".

The comment was written by a staff member if the `span` element contains `username--staff`. I already tried to use a if-loop in the items file but this didn't work.

As you may have noticed I'm pretty new to this stuff, so please forgive me if this was an incredible dumb question or if I did something wrong. I would be really thankful if someone could help me. :)

Here is my code:

Spider:

```html
class ComputerBaseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ComputerBase"
    start_urls = [
    'https://www.computerbase.de/forum/threads/in-eigener-sache-auch-wir-kommen-an-einem-consent-dialog-nicht-vorbei.1973328/',
     ]

    def parse(self, response):

        comments = response.xpath( '//*/div[@class = "message-cell message-cell--main"]')

        for comment in comments:
            loader = ItemLoader(item = CBCrawlerItem(), selector = comment)

            loader.add_xpath('Comment_no','.//ul[@class="message-attribution-opposite message-attribution-opposite--list "]/li[2]/a/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('Datetime','.//time[@class="u-dt"]/@datetime')
            loader.add_xpath('Comment', './/*/article[@class = "message-body js-selectToQuote"]//div[@class = "bbWrapper"]//text()[not(ancestor::*[@class="js-extraPhrases"])]')
            loader.add_xpath('Admin', '..//span[contains(@class, "username--staff")]')


            yield loader.load_item()

        next_page = response.xpath('//*/a[@class="pageNav-jump pageNav-jump--next"]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

items file:

```html
def clean_data(data):
    data = data.strip()
    return data

def remove_quotes(text):
    #strip the unicode quotes
    text = text.strip(u'\u201c'u'\u201d')
    return text

def user_check(user):
    if response.xpath( '//*/div[@class = "message-cell message-cell--main"]..//span[contains(@class, "username--staff")]') is true:
        return "Admin"
    else:
        return "Customer"


class CBCrawlerItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:

    Comment_no = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(clean_data),
        output_processor=TakeFirst()
        )

    Datetime = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(),
        output_processor=TakeFirst()
        )

    Comment = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(clean_data, remove_quotes),
            output_processor=Identity()
        )

    Admin = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(user_check),
        output_processor=TakeFirst()
        )


    pass
```

This was my try:

```
loader.add_xpath('Admin', '..//span[contains(@class, "username--staff")]')

def user_check(user):
if response.xpath( '//*/div[@class = "message-cell message-cell--main"]..//span[contains(@class, "username--staff")]') is true:
    return "Admin"
else:
    return "Customer"
```

Comment: What problems are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

Tanks for the help. :) The Solution was a for loop:

```
def Check_Author(Authors):
for Author in Authors:
    return 'Admin'
```